# React Native Redux Reducer with Immutability Helper correct way to push an array

Tags: react-native, redux, immutable.js

I'm using react native with Redux and in my reducer using Immutability Helper what's the correct way to push a new item into my array? Here is my code

State

```
const initialState = {
    photos: [],
    comments:[],
    hasData:false,
};
```

Reducer

```
switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.INSERT_PHOTO:
            return update(state, {$push: [action.data]});
        case actionTypes.CLEAR_PHOTOS:
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

I have tried `update(state.photos, {$push: [action.data]});`

But that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing nested properly properly, try :

```
update(state, {
    photos: {$push: [action.data]}
});
```

You syntax returns the `photos` array, not the state, it most likely break redux state.

Comment: Thanks that was it